# How to predict with sklearn pipelines and imputation

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am reviewing the sklearn documentation page "Imputing missing values before building an estimator"
The relevant code is:

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.datasets import load_boston 
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer 
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score

rng = np.random.RandomState(0)

dataset = load_boston() 
X_full, y_full = dataset.data, dataset.target
n_samples = X_full.shape[0] 
n_features = X_full.shape[1]

estimator = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=0, n_estimators=100)
score = cross_val_score(estimator, X_full, y_full).mean() 
print("Score with the entire dataset = %.2f" % score)

# Add missing values in 75% of the lines
missing_rate = 0.75 
n_missing_samples = np.floor(n_samples * missing_rate) 
missing_samples = np.hstack((np.zeros(n_samples - n_missing_samples,
                                dtype=np.bool),
                       np.ones(n_missing_samples,
                               dtype=np.bool))) rng.shuffle(missing_samples) 
missing_features = rng.randint(0, n_features, n_missing_samples)

# Estimate the score without the lines containing missing values
X_filtered = X_full[~missing_samples, :] 
y_filtered = y_full[~missing_samples] estimator = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=0, n_estimators=100)          
score = cross_val_score(estimator, X_filtered, y_filtered).mean() 
print("Score without the samples containing missing values = %.2f" % score)

# Estimate the score after imputation of the missing values 
X_missing = X_full.copy()
X_missing[np.where(missing_samples)[0], missing_features] = 0 
y_missing = y_full.copy() 
estimator = Pipeline([("imputer", Imputer(missing_values=0,
                                          strategy="mean",
                                          axis=0)),
                      ("forest", RandomForestRegressor(random_state=0,
                                                       n_estimators=100))]) 
score = cross_val_score(estimator, X_missing, y_missing).mean() 
print("Score after imputation of the missing values = %.2f" % score)
```

Now I want to predict, which should be simple, but

```
estimator.predict(X=X_filtered[1:10,:])
```

returns the following error:

```
"AttributeError: 'Imputer' object has no attribute 'statistics_'"
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Please try to reformat your code, it is not very readable.

Comment: I don't see a call to the 'fit' or 'transform' methods in this mess of code. It is the source of the problem.

Comment: I have reformatted the code.  Sorry it did not import well.

Answer (score 0):

After studying a bit more I have figured this out.  The issue is that cross_val_score has generated multiple models and no one has been used for predicting.  Predict needs a single fitted model.  This could be solved in several ways, a simple one of which is here:

```
estimator.fit_transform(X_missing, y_missing)
estimator.predict(X=X_filtered[1:10,:])
```

Since the original example was using cross validation, another likely path would be to use GridSearchCV and then select using best_estimator_, but that is beyond the scope of this question.